# Auto set specific shipping class in Woocommerce when adding a product

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

When adding a product in Woocommerce, under the Shipping Tab, does anyone know how or if the dfefault selected shipping class choice can be changed.

Currently, when adding a new product, the shipping class is set to No Shipping Class but I would prefer for the default to be be set to Royal Mail which is a custom shipping class I have setup.

[image]

I have loked under all the options but nothing is there to move the choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trick by adding some JavaScript code in the Admin targeting "new" product pages only.

First you need to find out the numerical term Id for your "Royal" shipping class. For that, inspect the shipping class dropdown to get the related option value:

[image]

Now you can set your shipping class ID in the code below:

```php
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'custom_admin_product_js' );
function custom_admin_product_js() {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if( $pagenow === 'post-new.php' && $post_type === 'product' ):
    ?><script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery( function($) {
        var shippingClassID = '33'; // <= Here set you shipping class ID
        $('select#product_shipping_class').val(shippingClassID).change();
    });
    </script><?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Test the code and it worked as expected. Been trying to figure this out for some time, really appreciate the code, thank you